# Copy files from local window machine to remote windows machine using java

Tags: java, linux, windows, remote-desktop, jsch

I have searched a lot but couldn't get a solution for this. I need to copy a file from local windows machine to remote windows machine using java program. I have tried with JSch,

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = null;
    session = jsch.getSession("username","hostname",22);
    session.setPassword("password");
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.connect();
    ChannelSftp channel = null;
    channel = (ChannelSftp)session.openChannel("sftp");
    channel.connect();
        File localFile = new File("filePath");
        //If you want you can change the directory using the following line.
        channel.cd("E:/xxx");
    channel.put(new FileInputStream(localFile),localFile.getName());
        channel.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
```

While executing the above code, i am facing the below error,

```
Exception in thread "main" 2: No such file
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2846)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._realpath(ChannelSftp.java:2340)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.cd(ChannelSftp.java:342)
```

I have cygwin installed in remote windows machine. It seems Jsch is not able to find the windows path. The same code works properly when copying files from windows machine to linux machine.

Please tel me a solution for the above problem or is there any other options for this to achieve in java ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to resolve a Windows path with a drive letter you may need to use the [`/cygdrive` prefix](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#cygdrive). In this case, your `cd` method call should be called with the parameter `/cygdrive/e/xxx`.